# .append issues. Limit .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, keypress

I have a simple html text-box hooked up to a `.keypress(funcion(){...}` which makes a jquery icon show up next to it whenever I press a key on the keyboard. The purpose of this is to make a jquery ui icon appear when some input is entered into the text-box so that when the icon is clicked, it saves the user's input

It did what I want it to do... But we all know computer languages tend to be literal. Every time I press a key... A new save icon appears... EVERY TIME. Please help me, as I am stuck at this part..

P.S. For the jquery ui icon, it has a hover function to it..  when I put the icon

`<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></div>`

inside of the `.append`, it disables when it appears (disables the hover, thus staying one color). If this knowledge is about you how to enable the hover when it's coming from an append and you are willing to share, would be pretty cool.

```
        $(".solo1").keypress(function () {
        $("#kyo").append('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></div><br />');
    });
</script>
<div id="kyo"> <input class="solo1" /> </div>
```

Comment: Instead of adding it, check and see if it is already there?  What is hard about this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you might want to append once at e.g. page load, and only *show* the appropriate element in the `keypress` function.

Comment: Yes, correct.. Give the user the option to save when they enter something into the textbox.. Not to append a save button every time a key is pressed

Comment: You could also have a flag var and check/update it every time so you know if you need to append the icon. And add a handler for blur so you can hide the icon when the focus goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create all buttons at page load, and show the appropriate button when you press a key. Then hide it again when you click the button: http://jsfiddle.net/jC7TR/1/.

```
$('.solo1').after('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></div><br />')
.keypress(function() {
     $(this).next('.saveButton').show();
});

$('.saveButton').hide().click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Wonderful! This does exactly what I need it to. Thanks alot! You've also notified me of jsfiddle. What a neat website. Thanks again! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You have a few different options. First off, adding the button on keypress seems to be a little too frequent. You may want to add the button on another event such as `.change` or `.blur`. That being said, with your current code, all you would need to do is check if the button already exists, if it doesn't then append it.

```
$kyo = $("#kyo");  
if( $kyo.find('.saveButton').length === 0 ) // if button doesn't exist
    $kyo.append('<div class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all saveButton" title="Save" style="float:left; height:20px;" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-disk"></span></div><br />');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of on `keypress` could you use `.blur()` to have the icon appear after they click away from the textbox?

Comment: I like the way this goes about business, but it still has the same issue.. It will add a save button every time I click off of the textbox